# Google Chrome is keylogger?

Tags: network, keyloggers, chrome, security-theater

Hi i am a little bit worried that Google Chrome is logging my keystroke.
One time ago i had situation with chrome that when i clicked some where in input box he was writting key by key(even backspace) what i wrote, and searched in google(in past few days).

I use Kaspersky Pure 3.0. So i think that it would be hard to get infected in other way. 
I did full scan install application to scan keylogers and firewall.
And only one application asked about log what i wrote it was chrome.

I think maybe this is connected with synchronisation. Because in mobile i can saw what i googled on computer. But why google remember what i wrote on some forums. And why my OS replayed button witch i pressed multiple days ago.

EDIT
Some days ago i wrote post on some forum. And 2 days ago in other forum.

When i clicked in input dialog or search bar anywhere where i could write text.
My computer was writing for me everything i written in past 2 days on some webpages what i searched in google.
It was like record all keystroke i used in past days and replay them on input. I didnt touch keyboard but i was writting using backspace and text was from my old posts.

Comment: I see the you think Chrome may be logging your keystrokes, but I'm unclear what the exact repro steps are for the scenario that caused you concern.  Could you add detail to what exactly you saw?

Comment: Ok i added. If it was unclear i will add more explanation. I see that 3 people didnt understand.

Comment: I dont knew how to repro steps. It was one random situation. I restarted computer to fix this. It was replaying what i pressed for long time even chrome restarting didnt help.

Comment: Maybe it is good to close this thread. It was weired thats why i asked. And i dont knew how to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because you are logged in to your Google account when searching Google. Similarly, if you have autocomplete on, Chrome will provide a drop-down "suggestion" on common things, such as name, email address, etc.

Unless you can provide more details, at this point from what I can tell from your post, you are simply seeing expected behavior. Google Chrome is not "keylogging" in the sense that it is capturing your credit card numbers and sending them to bad people.

There are ways to turn off autocomplete and search history synchronization in Chrome settings and in your Google Account settings.

Comment: I knew about this but it is not this. I knew that google synchronize search history and etc. But why is remembering all keys i used and replaying. Maybe this is not chrome but i think that maybe this is some bug in synchronization.